# Convergence of the map $\mathbf q_{n+1}\gets\mathbf z+\tfrac1 2\operatorname{diag}\left[(\mathbf A+\operatorname{diag}[e^{\mathbf q_n}])^{-1}\right]$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given symmetric positive-definite matrix $\mathbf A$ and (real-valued) vectors $\mathbf q$ and $\mathbf z$, does the following iteration converge to a (unique) fixed point for $n\to \infty$?

$$
\mathbf q_{n+1} \gets \mathbf z + \tfrac 1 2 \operatorname{diag}\left[(\mathbf A + \operatorname{diag}[e^{\mathbf q_n}])^{-1}\right]
$$

This iteration comes from inside some log-Gaussian Cox process code. It *seems to converge* for all the values I've tried, but I can't seem to prove it.

##### Edit:

If it helps, $\mathbf A$ can be circulant (it is in my application anyway).

Comment: How is defined diag of a matrix ?

Comment: ah! extracts main diagonal as a vector; is there a more standard notation?